# Prove that sum of a positive matrix and a positive definite matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-matrices

Let $A$ be a positive matrix, and $B$ be a positive definite matrix. Prove that $A+B$ is invertible.

---

I tried to use the prove of positive definite implies invertible, but there is nothing I can use from the property of being a positive matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is incorrect. Take
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\2&1\end{pmatrix}, \ \ B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then
$$A+B=\begin{pmatrix}2&2\\2&2\end{pmatrix}$$
is singular.